# Como passar um texto da base de dados para exibi-lo como link num site

Tags: php, html, mysql

Olá, eu estou a fazer um site em php e html, ligado a uma base de dados em mysql.

E tenho uma tabela de noticias na base de dados, com os campos idartigos, titulo, texto e link.

O link está a passar em texto e eu gostaria de quando alguém visse a notícia no site, passa-se a ser link, de maneira que a pessoa clicasse.
Alguém me pode ajudar?

```
 $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM artigos WHERE activo = 1 ORDER BY idartigos DESC");
                                    while($row_artigos = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                                    {                       
                                echo "<br><br>";
                                echo($row_artigos[1]);
                                echo "<br>";
                                echo($row_artigos[2]);
            # tirar # qdo tiver link        echo($row_artigos[3]);          

                                echo "<br><br>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve utilizar a tag `<a>` e atribuir o valor de `$row_artigos[3]` ao atributo `href`.

Exemplo:

```
echo '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$row_artigos[3].'</a>';
```

**Editada:**

```
$link = $row_artigos[3];
if (strpos($link,'http') === false)
  $link = 'http://'.$link;

echo '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$row_artigos[3].'</a>';
```

Comment: sim @carlosandrade porém esse código não faz as pessoas serem redirecionadas ao local que o link aponta, imaginando que coloco www.google.pt eu queria que a pessoa ao clicar no link fosse redirecionada para esse site.

Comment: Não faz? Este exemplo deve imprimir na sua página algo como: `<a href="http://www.google.pt">http://www.google.pt</a>`. Lembrando que para o link funcionar, você deve gravar no seu banco de dados também o protocolo na url, que seria exatamente assim: `http://www.google.pt` e não apenas `www.google.pt`.

Comment: Se você não grava o protocolo no campo da sua tabela (`http://` ou `https://`) você pode acrescentá-lo ao gerar o link: `echo '<a href="http://'.$row_artigos[3].'">'.$row_artigos[3].'</a>';`

Comment: +1 é isso mesmo!!

Comment: Vou fazer uma edição na resposta para fazer uma verificação para caso o protocolo não esteja inserido no campo, o mesmo ser inserido.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que esteja buscando implementar um link comum em sua página...

Aqui existe um exemplo de implementação: [Exemplo de implementação de links](http://pt-br.html.net/tutorials/html/lesson8.php)

O que desejar exibir como link sempre será inserido dentro da tag '`<a>`', realize uma pesquisa de utilização desta tag que poderá aplicar de maneira mais eficaz.

Answer (score 0):

Você quer que o titulo vire um link?
Se é isso pode fazer assim:

```
echo "<a href='".$link."'>".$titulo."</a>";
```

Não deu para entender direito a pergunta, pode ser mais clara?

Comment: quero que o campo link(que é texto) vire um link ao ser mostrado no site.

Answer (score 0):

Para o texto exibido ser o conteúdo da coluna 1, e o link, o conteúdo da coluna 3:

```
   echo("<a href='".$row_artigos[3]."'>".$row_artigos[1]."</a>");
```

Para texto e link serem da mesma coluna:

```
echo("<a href='".$row_artigos[3]."'>".$row_artigos[3]."</a>");
```

Comment: Tá quase perfeito o código, mas imaginando que o link era google.pt eu queria que ao clicar pudesse ser redirecionada ao google.pt e esse não está a resultar

Comment: o google.pt deve estar dentro de `$row_artigos[3]` e o texto que quer exibir como link dentro de `$row_artigos[1]`. Qual problema esta acontecendo ?

Comment: não pode ser '$row_artigos[1]' tem de ser '$row_artigos[3] porque é no campo 3, que se chama link

Comment: um é o texto que irá exibir, o outro a url do link, não ?!

Comment: o resultado final deve ser algo do tipo: `<a href='http://google.pt'>Meu texto do link</a>`

Comment: os campos na minha base de dados sao: idartigos, título, texto, e link. O campo link é o row_artigos[3] e quando adiciono uma noticia o link está em texto normal, eu queria que ao passar para o site, os clientes pudessem ver esse texto "link" como uma hiperligação e que desse para clicarem e serem redirecionados ao tal link